# Following cfquery result is driving me crazy

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, coldfusion-8, cfml

I'm running the following query for many hours, made all sorts of changes but wondering why the DETAIL Query is not returning any results. I have similar queries with me for other connections as well( FIRSTCONN, SECONDCONN, FOURTHCONN) which are running absolutely fine and displaying desired range of dates in the output. Could anyone figure out what could be the reason?

```
<cfquery datasource = "XX.XX.X.XX" name="master">
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(date_format(Timedetail,'%m-%d-%Y'),'%m-%d-%Y') as THIRDCONN,count(Timedetail) as THIRDOCCURANCES ,EVENTS 
FROM MyDatabase
WHERE EVENTS = "THIRD" 
GROUP BY THIRDCONN;
 </cfquery> 


  DUMP FOR THIRD MASTER <cfdump var = "#master#"> 





<cfquery dbtype="query" name="detail">
SELECT  *
FROM master 
WHERE THIRDCONN  >= <cfqueryparam value="#form.startdate#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date"> 
AND THIRDCONN  <  <cfqueryparam value="#form.enddate#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">;
</cfquery>  


   DUMP FOR THIRD DETAIL <cfdump var = "#detail#">
```

P.S. Just as a test, I ran "SELECT * from master" in the detail query and I got the identical output for master and detail queries which was expected but when I mention the dates parameters in the detail query, it stops displaying the output.However, this is not the case with other connection queries (FIRSTCONN, SECONDCONN, FOURTHCONN etc)

Is there any other way I can run this query or any mistake I have done?

DUMP FOR THIRD MASTER

```
        THIRDCONN   THIRDOCCURANCES     EVENTS
   1   {ts '2013-06-06 00:00:00'}   10810   THIRD
2   {ts '2013-06-07 00:00:00'}  8076    THIRD
3   {ts '2013-06-10 00:00:00'}  25043   THIRD
4   {ts '2013-06-11 00:00:00'}  24754   THIRD
5   {ts '2013-06-12 00:00:00'}  14587   THIRD
6   {ts '2013-06-13 00:00:00'}  24828   THIRD
7   {ts '2013-06-14 00:00:00'}  23987   THIRD
8   {ts '2013-06-15 00:00:00'}  28027   THIRD
9   {ts '2013-06-16 00:00:00'}  25190   THIRD
10  {ts '2013-06-17 00:00:00'}  27255   THIRD
11  {ts '2013-06-18 00:00:00'}  22227   THIRD
12  {ts '2013-06-19 00:00:00'}  15951   THIRD
13  {ts '2013-06-20 00:00:00'}  21120   THIRD
14  {ts '2013-06-21 00:00:00'}  24214   THIRD
15  {ts '2013-06-22 00:00:00'}  22466   THIRD
16  {ts '2013-06-23 00:00:00'}  19881   THIRD
17  {ts '2013-06-24 00:00:00'}  23479   THIRD
18  {ts '2013-06-25 00:00:00'}  7879    THIRD
```

DUMP FOR THIRD DETAIL

THIRDCONN   THIRDOCCURANCES     EVENTS

Comment: are you sure you're getting valid values for #form.startdate# and #form.enddate#; could there be NULLS in your db causing the issue?

Comment: Yes, I tested it using `<cfdump var="#form.startdate#">
<cfdump var="#form.enddate#">`. Where do you mean NULL could be present?

Comment: This sounds like the exact same [problem from your other thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17684464/104223). **Do not mix data types**. If you want to perform a date comparison, your database query must return a **date object**, not a string (which is what `date_format` returns). ie Use `STR_TO_DATE` to return a date object.

Comment: Or just return timedetail if it is a date or time data type.

Comment: @Leigh I remember that you mentioned about `STR_TO_DATE` function and I tried using that as well but it didn't work. Also, when I use `STR_TO_DATE` function, I don't see my output in the mm/dd/yyyy format.Instead it remains as it is.

Comment: You can always use ColdFusion's dateForamt() function to format the date. Don't worry about formatting it in your SQL.

Comment: @Tan - Aside from the mask, this query is no different than the one in the other thread. So I really do not see how it is possible that adding `STR_TO_DATE` does not work. Unless there really are no records for the FORM dates you have entered. What are the dates you entered for the original data dump you posted?

Comment: @Leigh By not working, I meant that there was no change in the output here. I used DATE() and it worked for me in addition to specified mask in my post below.

Comment: Since the question "why the DETAIL Query is not returning any results", was [already answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17684464/104223) (returning a string instead of a date), I am voting to close this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured out on my own. There is no need of `STR_TO_DATE` function in SQL Query here.I just used `DATE()` function to retrieve the date part. Also, I noticed that specifying the mask while using `DateFormat` function as `yyyy-mm-dd` was helpful for coldfusion rather than specifying any other format.

Thanks to all for your help. Appreciated.

**Working Code:**

```
<cfparam name="form.startdate" default="#DateFormat(dateAdd('d',-40,now()), 'yyyy-mm-dd')#">
<cfparam name="form.enddate" default="#DateFormat(dateAdd('d',-1,now()), 'yyyy-mm-dd')#">


<cfquery datasource = "XX.XX.X.XX" name="master">
SELECT DATE(Timedetail) as THIRDCONN,count(Timedetail) as THIRDOCCURANCES ,EVENTS 
FROM MyDatabase
WHERE EVENTS = "THIRD" 
GROUP BY THIRDCONN;
 </cfquery> 





<cfquery dbtype="query" name="detail">
SELECT  *
FROM master 
WHERE THIRDCONN  >= <cfqueryparam value="#form.startdate#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date"> 
AND THIRDCONN  <  <cfqueryparam value="#form.enddate#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">;
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Instead of *describing* what you did, can you post your final code?

Comment: Sure, Should I post it over my original question? Or Just below that?

Comment: No, you want to preserve the "question". Otherwise, when someone reads it in the future, this answer won't make any sense ;-) Just [update this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17840934/edit). I am curious to see it because, using `DATE()` should return the same thing as wrapping `STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(...date only mask ..))`. So really it should not make any difference.

Comment: *RE: the DETAIL Query is not returning any results* Are you saying the QoQ **did** return results using DATE(), but **did not** return results using `STR_TO_DATE( DATE_FORMAT(..date only mask..), '%m-%d-%Y')`? Truthfully .. I have a hard time believing that ;-). I ran your code w/CF8 + MySQL and it worked just fine. So I suspect there is something more you are not telling us here ...

Comment: Yes, you are right. By the way, I'm using MySQL Server 5.5. Does this makes any difference? I didn't mention about it I believe.

Comment: Well since we know that using `date()` did not solve your original QoQ problem ;-) (which makes the above answer wrong, btw) ... what issue DID it solve (if any)? Coincidentally, that is the same MySQL version I used. But always good to mention your version in query questions.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you have a `NULL` value in your database which is throwing off your query. Try running the query with something like this

```
WHERE isNull(THIRDCONN,getDate())  >= <cfqueryparam value="#form.startdate#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date"> 
AND isNull(THIRDCONN,getDate())<  <cfqueryparam value="#form.enddate#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">;
```

Where you can use any date value in place of `getDate()` if you have `NULL` values then this will confirm that issue.

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow once I have access to my workstation. Thanks

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by "use any value in place of getDate()" in the context of my question. Please clarify.

Comment: if you have `NULL` values in the database you can set them to any date you want. Depends on if you want them included in the query or not.

Answer (score 1):

As Leigh suggested, your query is actually returning a string for the date, rather than a real date. CF has issues with mixed data types in QoQ - the second query is trying to compare a date with a string, which can give wonky results as you noted.

Try changing the first query to:

```
<cfquery datasource = "XX.XX.X.XX" name="master">
   SELECT Timedetail as THIRDCONN,count(Timedetail) as     THIRDOCCURANCES ,EVENTS 
   FROM MyDatabase
   WHERE EVENTS = "THIRD" 
   GROUP BY THIRDCONN;
</cfquery>
```

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow once I have access to my workstation. Thanks

Comment: can you give some more details about what exactly did not work?